# How to post form data to directory?

Tags: php, forms, post

I have the following code in an html file:

```
<form action="some/directory" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="foo" id="foo" value="bar">
</form>
```

And the following code in the index.php of some/directory:

```
echo ( $_POST["foo"] );
```

But I keep getting an "undefined variable" error.

Does the form recipient HAVE to be a file (e.g. `action="some/directory/index.php"` or can it be a directory (e.g. `action="some/directory"`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that `action="some/directory/"` includes the trailing slash (`/`) at the end of the directory name!

Then it works!